# Summarize pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, summarization

I want to summarize pandas DataFrame file. This one is like this ->

```
City      Name      Date
London    Joey      1998
Vegas     Chandler  1999
```

So result will be like this. In 1998 Joey was in London. In 1999 Chandler was in Vegas.
Something like this. Is there any workaround ? or which modules help me in doing this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting to have the result in a new column of the dataframe?

Comment: Hello. I want to save those sentences in the .doc/.docx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you really only need to iterate over the rows. Using a list comprehension is going to be faster than using `iterrows:

### If you want to modify DataFrame:

Here, we use `DataFrame.apply` to, well, "apply" the function over each row:

```
def format_row(row):
    return f"In {row['Date']}, {row['Name']} was in {row['City']}."

df = df.apply(lambda r: format_row(r), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0       In 1998, Joey was in London.
1    In 1999, Chandler was in Vegas.
```

### If you want to get sentences as list:

You can define a function that formats the row, like so:

```
def format_row(row):
    return f"In {row[0]}, {row[1]} was in {row[2]}."
```

And then use the list comprehension to `zip` the row accordingly and pass it to the function.

```
rows = [format_row(r) for r in zip(df["Date"], df["Name"], df["City"])]
```

If these columns are the only columns in the `DataFrame`, using `DataFrame.values` will be cleaner, but provide the same output:

```
rows = [format_row(r) for r in df.values]
```

In that case, you'll have to swap the index values within the function:

```
return f"In {row[2]}, {row[1]} was in {row[0]}."
```

Answer (score 2):

With this csv:

```
City,Name,Date
London,Joey,1998
Vegas,Chandler,1999
```

You can use the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(f"In {df.iloc[i,2]}, {df.iloc[i,0]} was in {df.iloc[i,1]}.")
```

It iterates over the rows of the dataframe, and uses a format prefix in the string to print the sentence with values from each row using `df.iloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Given data

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['London','Joey','1998'],['Vegas','Chandler','1999']],columns=['City','Name','Date'])
```

Add a new column as a summary if you need or you can have it in the list as @gmdev suggested.

```
df['Summary']=df.apply(lambda x: 'In '+str(x.Date)+' '+str(x.Name)+' was in '+str(x.City),axis=1)
```

[image]